# How to get the address that one machine instruction write to?

Tags: linux, debugging, disassembly, instructions

Now i have got a machine instruction'address from EIP register. This machine instruction could change the value of a certain area of memory, i do want but cannot get the address of this memory.

Of course,i could read the data from machine instruction'address, but the content is machine instruction like:0x8b0c4d8b......, it's unreadable(i can not use debugging tools like gdb).

How to get the address that one  machine instruction will write to?

Comment: Use a debugger - set a breakpoint at the address of that instruction, then examine EIP when you hit the breakpoint - it's the only reliable way.

Comment: But the EIP is the instruction's address,am i right? I still can not get the address that this instruction will write to.

Comment: I think @PaulR misspoke; nevertheless, it's still true that you will have to use a disassembler (or tool with one built in) or write your own tool that knows how to disassemble x86 opcodes.

Comment: @geekosaur, i have write my own debug tools,it's a simple debugger without symbol supporting and disassemble supporting. But seems it's difficult to disassemble x86 opcodes.

Comment: Sorry - I meant "examine the relevant register(s)", not "examine EIP" of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the machine code EIP points to and you just want to disassemble it, do something like this (I took your example of `0x8b0c4d8b`):

```
#create binary file
$ echo -en "\x8b\x0c\x4d\x8b" > foo.bin

#disassemble it
$ objdump -D -b binary -m i386 foo.bin 

foo.bin:     file format binary


Disassembly of section .data:

00000000 :
   0:   8b                      .byte 0x8b
   1:   0c 4d                   or     $0x4d,%al
   3:   8b                      .byte 0x8b
```

So, in this case, it doesn't change any memory location but if it did, you can easily see it from the assembly code.

**Edit:** It seems from the comments that you want to do this programmatically. Take a look at [udis86](http://udis86.sourceforge.net/). It allows [examining operands](http://udis86.sourceforge.net/manual/manual.html#id482430) of instructions. For ARM, see [disarm](https://launchpad.net/libdisarm).

Comment: This won't work in the general case though - only for hard-coded addresses (i.e. not when register-based addressing is involved) - the only reliable method is to run the code under a debugger and inspect the relevant register(s).

Comment: @PaulR: Yep, I know. I provided this answer because the OP mentioned he cannot use a debugger.

Comment: Yes - I didn't know whether "i can not use debugging tools like gdb" meant "I do not know *how* to use debugging tools like gdb" or "there is some *technical reason* why I can not use debugging tools like gdb" ?

Comment: there is some technical reason that i can not use it. i want this process to be done by my own process, that's why i write a smaller debugger.

Comment: @AlanGame: udis86 is a library, you can call it from your own process.

Comment: @Job Thanks,it's a great job, any lib for arm?